# Creating a database got stuck in command line

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have installed `mysql-installer-community-8.0.20.0` in my windows10 Pro laptop. Navigate to `services.msc`, I could see the MYSQL server is up and running.

Now run the command prompt as administrator, I have connected to mysql by `mysql -u admin -p` and provided the password, it connected successfully and displays 
*Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 12
Server version: 8.0.20 MySQL Community Server - GPL*

For creating a database I ran the below query, but nothing happened, I couldn't see any database listed after running `show databases`. Should I need to install anything else here ?

I am also using `Dbeaver 7.0.5` version, I have created a Database connection, but displays error " Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'"

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE soccerreact DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

[image]

Comment: You might try [searching on Stack Overflow for the error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Unable+to+load+authentication+plugin+%27caching_sha2_password%27).

Comment: Thank you, I saw that earlier, I have got a `admin` user and a password already. Should I need to alter the admin user, as per following query >>>  ALTER USER 'student'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'pass123';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon at the end;

Comment: oh mate that works like a charm, absolutely helpful. Any idea about my second problem `Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'"`

Comment: I am not familiar with DBeaver, but it seems like you need to configure legacy authentication.  See if there is a configuration to use Mysql 5.x method